# ExoPlayer to stream MP4 file

Tags: android, video-streaming, exoplayer

i´m having so many problem to integrate ExoPlayer to my project.

I have add all library files and i don´t know how configure to play a url with .mp4 file.

Now i use this method to play URL with mp4:

```
String uri = data.urlserver + datafile.getMedia_url_one();  
mediaController.setAnchorView(zoomVideoView);
zoomVideoView.setVideoPath(uri.replaceAll(" ", "%20"));  
zoomVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController); 
zoomVideoView.requestFocus();
zoomVideoView.start();
```

I have no idea how to implement to ExoPlayer play the videos.

Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ExoMedia library wraps exoplayer See examples on [github](https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia/)

Comment: Thank you. I have copy all library and res but i don´t know how apply this to my code... i´m beginner in Android code

Comment: if you look at the documentation everything is crystal clear..
1. add dependency and sync grade..2. add xml code in your layout file.. 3 open your activity and fragment and add setupVideoView(); function

Comment: if you still cannot figure out i suggest you to start learning to build android apps from scratch  follow this source to learn android app developer as beginner https://www.udacity.com/course/android-development-for-beginners--ud837